# Navigating a javascript object (previous and next)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue3 together with [Collect.js](https://collect.js.org/). I have an object `records` that can have `n` number of items.

On my website, I display these records - one by one. The current record is captured by a variable called `current`

Users can navigate through the records (previous or next):

```html
<button @click="navigateRecords('previous')" type="button">
    Previous
</button>
<button @click="navigateRecords('next')" type="button">
    Next Record
</button>
```

I have a method called `navigateRecords` as per below code. Please note that I have to append a key to the current record, called `completion`.

```javascript
const props = defineProps({
    records: {
        type: Object,
    },
})

const currentRecordIndex = ref(0);
const current = ref({...collect(props.records.first()), completion: ''});

const navigateRecords = (direction) => {
    //If user is clicking on "Next"
    if (direction === 'next') {
        //If we are at the end of the object, return to first record, else get the next.
        if (currentRecordIndex.value === collect(props.records).count() - 1) {
            currentRecordIndex.value = 0;
        } else {
            currentRecordIndex.value++;
        }
    } else {
        //If we are at the end of the object, return to first record, else get the previous.
        if (currentRecordIndex.value > 0) {
            currentRecordIndex.value--;
        }else{
            currentRecordIndex.value = collect(props.records).count() - 1;
        }
    }

    //Set the current record, to the one navigated to.
    let newValue = collect(props.records).slice(currentRecordIndex.value).first();
    current.value = {
        ...newValue,
        completion: newValue.completion || ''
    }

}
```

I find the above code very messy, and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this - perhaps even without using `collect.js`. Either way, I am using Vue3's composition API .

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue, so don't really understand the `ref` and `collect` constructs, but at the very least you can split this into two functions, `navigateNext`, and `navigatePrevious` (passing a string to indicate direction is overly verbose and prone to typos).  Also, if you want just one value out of the collection, just use the index accessor (`collect(props.records)[0]`) rather than `slice`.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Good points about splitting them into two distinct methods. I was also looking for ways to perhaps optimize the `if if else` usage...

Comment: The outer `if` is dealing with direction, so if you split into two functions, you won't need that level.  That just leaves `if ... else ...`

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the logic, you can make `direction` into an `offset` instead and pass it the value `1` (for next) or `-1` (for previous)

```
currentRecordIndex.value += offset;
```

And to handle the wrapping in case of out of bounds, you can use the modulo operator:

```
let length = collect(props.records).count();
currentRecordIndex.value = (currentRecordIndex.value + length) % length;
```

This allows you to get rid of the entire outer if-else construct.

I am not familiar with collect.js, nor do I know what kind of object `props.records` are, but if it's a simple array, I would recommend using the `.length` property of it instead.